# Needs an explanation about Hash member of SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES_HASH struct

Tags: c, winapi

### Overview

According to MSDN, [SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES_HASH struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb394725(v=vs.85).aspx) is defined as follows:

```c
typedef struct _SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES_HASH {
  DWORD               SidCount;
  PSID_AND_ATTRIBUTES SidAttr;
  SID_HASH_ENTRY      Hash[SID_HASH_SIZE];
} SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES_HASH, *PSID_AND_ATTRIBUTES_HASH;
```

When I tried to call [GetTokenInformation()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671(v=vs.85).aspx) with its *TokenHandle* parameter set to the token handle of the current process and its *TokenInformationClass* parameter set to `TokenAccessInformation`, the [SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES_HASH struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb394725(v=vs.85).aspx) pointed by **SidHash** member contains information as follows (in my system):

- **SidCount** member equals 16.
- **SidAttr** member points to an array of 16 [SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379595(v=vs.85).aspx) structs.
- **Hash** member contains an array of 32 hash values.

It is said that the **Hash** member is an array of pointers to hash values. These values correspond to the [SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379595(v=vs.85).aspx) structs pointed to by the *SidAttr* parameter.

Sorry, I cannot not fully understand the explanation.

### Question

Hash values of what?

I thought, if each hash value correspond to each SID in the array of [SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379595(v=vs.85).aspx) structs (which are 16 SIDs in my system), why there are 32 hash values???

Thanks in advance.

### Updates

Here are the 16 SIDs I get:

- S-1-5-21-1413122000-1259115538-2916509531-1001
- S-1-5-21-1413122000-1259115538-2916509531-513
- S-1-1-0
- S-1-5-114
- S-1-5-32-544
- S-1-5-32-559
- S-1-5-32-545
- S-1-5-4
- S-1-2-1
- S-1-5-11
- S-1-5-15
- S-1-5-113
- S-1-5-5-0-102823280
- S-1-2-0
- S-1-5-64-10
- S-1-16-12288

and these are the 32 hash values I get:

- 45076
- 2370
- 8
- 0
- 128
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 1
- 16384
- 512
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 1056
- 59270
- 0
- 112
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 6152
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 1
- 0

Comment: Hack attack countermeasure: https://books.google.com/books?id=ifQPC86G66sC&pg=PA419&lpg=PA419&dq=windows+SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES_HASH+compare+hash&source=bl&ots=WT_dmfowI3&sig=2flSsMikkBDnx678ew2TM9UecH0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjeypDu4ufbAhXH6oMKHRrcDmQQ6AEIUjAE#v=onepage&q=windows%20SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES_HASH%20compare%20hash&f=false

Comment: this not 32 hash values, this single common hash (bit-fields). also in user mode exist `NTSTATUS NTAPI RtlSidHashInitialize(PSID_AND_ATTRIBUTES psa, ULONG n, PSID_AND_ATTRIBUTES_HASH psah);` and 
`PVOID NTAPI RtlSidHashLookup(PSID_AND_ATTRIBUTES_HASH psah, PSID Sid);` but i not sure for what this need